# Scrolling the terminal line by line from the keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to scroll the terminal using the keyboard in Visual Studio Code line by line? I often find I need to look back in the REPL and using the mouse is pretty unergonomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for `scroll` in the keyboard shortcuts you will see a few that apply to the terminal, including

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd>

that will scroll the terminal up by a line.  You could always rebind that if you wish.