# How to make smooth scrolling in VSC terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in VSC and writting nodejs and I am faced with a scroll problem in long terminal outputs, scroll on the right side of terminal with slider goes too many rows too fast if I use them, so, question is, do we have smooth scroll option in integrated terminal to read output easy and line by line with arrows or we must use another external terminal for that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

In v1.71 smooth scrolling will be improved, see [Release Notes: Terminal Smooth Scrolling](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#smooth-scrolling).

> The terminal now supports smooth scrolling which will animate
> scrolling over a short period to help orient yourself after scrolling,
> like the feature that is also available in the editor and lists. To
> enable it set:
>
> `json "terminal.integrated.smoothScrolling": true`

---

In vscode v1.42 (early February, 2020) two new commands related to terminal **mouse wheel** scroll sensitivity will be introduced:

> Scrolling sensitivity
>
> The terminal's scrolling sensitivity can now be configured independent
> of the editor using the new settings
> `terminal.integrated.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity` and
> `terminal.integrated.fastScrollSensitivity`.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#scrolling-sensitivity

---

Thanks to @Sean and  @user9811991 in the comments for pointing out that the setting is a multiplier.  My terminal normally scroll three lines at a time, to get it to scroll only one line I had to set `terminal.integrated.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity` to `0.08`.

---

Also see [Scrolling the terminal line by line from the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683551/scrolling-the-terminal-line-by-line-from-the-keyboard) for a keyboard command that scrolls the terminal by one line: `workbench.action.terminal.scrollUp` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd>

Comment: For now best option is external terminal.

Comment: Keep in mind that there settings are multipliers so if you wish to slow down scrolling set it to something like 0.5 not -2. Yes this took me longer than expected to figure out.

Comment: On my system I set `terminal.integrated.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity` to `0.1` to scroll two lines at a time. `0.05` scrolls one line at a time for me.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll add this to the answer.  I have to use `0.08` to scroll one line.  `0.5` still scrolls 3 lines at once.

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125950 (released to Insiders)

Answer (score 3):

Just add these lines into settings.json file and it will take effect instantly.

```
"terminal.integrated.fastScrollSensitivity" :1 ,
"terminal.integrated.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity":0.1
```

I've added the values as 0.1 because it was better for me , you can choose your sweet spot.

[settings.json file , where you need to add the above answered values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG5Lw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It has been [implemented in *xterm*](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/pull/3940)

To enable smooth scrolling in VSCODE terminal, go to your **settings**, search for `terminal smo` and
simply toggle it on:

[image]

Comment: No Settings Found

Comment: Update your VSCODE maybe? I see it with my own eyes right now

Comment: Uhh, sorry, it seems I disabled automatic updates. The option is available indeed. Btw the option works kinda weird: when your scroll works per 1 line already, it just adds some delay, not smoothly scrolling each individual line. Useful for people who setup scrolling step to 2+ lines. But isn't what I expected.

Comment: So write the *vscode* team in their Github issues page :)