# tmux in vscode - slow down scrolling speed

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmux, iterm2

I am trying to tweak the scroll buffer or speed of [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

At present, I have below lines in my `~/.tmux.conf` which works fine in `iTerm2` but does not behave at all. Scrolling is really fast in VS Code even with the slightest movement of the mouse.

```
run-shell ~/.tmuxd/tmux-better-mouse-mode/scroll_copy_mode.tmux
set -g mouse on
set -g @scroll-speed-num-lines-per-scroll 1
```

Not sure if it matters, but here are my settings of the integrated terminal in VS Code.

```json
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [
        "-l"
    ],
```

Comment: I tried the settings described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921221/how-to-make-smooth-scrolling-in-vsc-terminal but they don't work in VS Code tmux :-(

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?