# How to change mouse scroll speed(sensitivity) in VS Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already read answer to this question on stack overflow which did seem to work....UNTIL... until I closed VS code. when I opened it again, I had to go to settings.json file, make some change and do ctrl+s for it to work it again. So the question is, what do I do so that it won't need me to go to settings.json file every time I open my VS Code for the mouse scroll sensitivity change to work.

Comment: What do you write in *settings.json*? And with "I already read answer to this question on stack overflow…" do you mean this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921221/how-to-make-smooth-scrolling-in-vsc-terminal)?

Answer (score 0):

open Visual Studio Code, and click Settings. Click Settings. Click Text Editor. Click Fast Scroll sensitivity box.

Answer (score 0):

Find in vs code settings "Mouse Wheel Scroll Sensitivity". The default value is 1.